# GitLab CI can't find composer.json in container

Tags: docker, gitlab

I am having a problem with my GitLab CI pipeline. For my Laravel project, I have an `install` stage, which should install my composer packages. Here is the pipeline code for composer:

```
include:
  - project: 'gitlab-ci/templates'
    ref: v1.0.0
    file: 'pipeline-template.yml'

stages:
  - install

image: docker:20.10.16

variables:
  DOCKER_HOST: "tcp://docker-service:2375"


composer-install-production:
  extends: .custom-composer-install
  variables:
      COMPOSER_ARGS: "--ignore-platform-reqs --no-ansi --no-interaction --no-progress --optimize-autoloader --prefer-dist --no-dev --no-scripts"
  before_script:
    - echo $CONTAINER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD | docker login -u $CONTAINER_REGISTRY_USERNAME $CONTAINER_REGISTRY_URL --password-stdin
    - cp .env.pipeline .env
  only:
    - tags


.custom-composer-install:
  extends: .composer-install
  variables:
    COMPOSER_TAG: "2"
    COMPOSER_SSH_DEPLOY_KEY: $GITLAB_RUNNER_RSA
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - .env
      - public/
      - vendor/
      - storage/
```

And in my `gitlab-ci/templates` project I have a file called `composer.yml` which contains this:

```
.composer-install:

  # Default variables
  variables:
    PROJECT_PATH:             ""
    COMPOSER_TAG:             "prestissimo" # Change composer tag to use a differrent version.
    COMPOSER_ARGS:            "--ignore-platform-reqs --no-ansi --no-interaction --no-progress --optimize-autoloader --prefer-dist" # If provided, composer arguments are added to the install.
    COMPOSER_AUTHJSON:        "" # If provided, authentication can be added to install private packages like Nova.
    COMPOSER_SSH_DEPLOY_KEY:  "" # If provided, adds an SSH key to the composer image to access private packages.

  stage: install

  before_script:
    - echo $CONTAINER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD | docker login -u $CONTAINER_REGISTRY_USERNAME $CONTAINER_REGISTRY_URL --password-stdin

  script:
    - PROJECT_PATH=$(pwd)
    - echo $PROJECT_PATH
    - cd $PROJECT_PATH
    - ls
    - >
      if [ "$COMPOSER_AUTHJSON" != "" ]; then
        echo $COMPOSER_AUTHJSON > auth.json
      fi
    - >
      if [ "$COMPOSER_SSH_DEPLOY_KEY" == "" ]; then
        docker run --volume "${PROJECT_PATH}":/app --rm $CONTAINER_REGISTRY_URL/internal/docker/composer:${COMPOSER_TAG} install $COMPOSER_ARGS
      else
        docker run --volume "${PROJECT_PATH}":/app --rm -e "SSH_DEPLOY_KEY=$COMPOSER_SSH_DEPLOY_KEY" $CONTAINER_REGISTRY_URL/internal/docker/composer:${COMPOSER_TAG} install --ignore-platform-reqs $COMPOSER_ARGS
      fi

  artifacts:
    name: "$CI_JOB_ID-$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME"
    expire_in: 1 day
    paths:
      - vendor/

  interruptible: true
```

The problem I am having is in the template part. I already have some debug lines added, but the for now focus on the docker run command:

```
docker run --volume "${PROJECT_PATH}":/app --rm -e "SSH_DEPLOY_KEY=$COMPOSER_SSH_DEPLOY_KEY" $CONTAINER_REGISTRY_URL/internal/docker/composer:${COMPOSER_TAG} install --ignore-platform-reqs $COMPOSER_ARGS
```

This command should mount my laravel repository files starting from the root to the `/app` directory inside the composer container, because thats where the composer container looks for the `composer.json`. Now running this command returns the following error:

> Composer could not find a composer.json file in /app To initialize a
> project, please create a composer.json file. See
> https://getcomposer.org/basic-usage Cleaning up project directory and
> file based variables 00:00 ERROR: Job failed: command terminated with
> exit code 1

To debug this, I printed the value of the `$PROJECT_PATH` and this contains: `/builds/Projects/project1/laravel-api`, which is correct. Then I use the change directory command to go inside that folder and run ls to list all the files. This results the following list:

```
Makefile
app
artisan
bootstrap
composer.json
composer.lock
config
database
docker
docker-compose-test.yml
docker-compose.yml
package.json
phpunit.xml
public
readme.md
resources
routes
scripts
server.php
storage
tests
webpack.mix.js
```

As you can see there is a composer.json listed, so to debug this further I changed the docker volume mount to:

```
--volume /builds/Projects/project1/laravel-api:/app
```

But this results in the same error. I am running out of ideas why this is happening, so I am hoping that someone could help me out.

### Extra info

This GitLab installation runs inside a kubernetes cluster, so that's why I define this:

```
image: docker:20.10.16

variables:
  DOCKER_HOST: "tcp://docker-service:2375"
```

Because I need to run docker-in-docker, I created an separate docker.sock so the host machine isn't affected by any of the things that happen in the pipeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to run docker-in-docker

And that is the issue. The docker command (`docker run --volume "${PROJECT_PATH}":/app --rm $CONTAINER_REGISTRY_URL/internal/docker/composer:${COMPOSER_TAG} install $COMPOSER_ARGS`) will create a container, install files, then *delete* that container.

The rest of the script will not benefit from whatever was done inside said container.

If you want to [est and deploy Laravel applications with GitLab CI/CD](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/examples/laravel_with_gitlab_and_envoy/), you need to use *one* [PHP-based Docker image](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/examples/laravel_with_gitlab_and_envoy/#create-a-container-image), that will be used by [`your gitlab-ci.yml`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/examples/laravel_with_gitlab_and_envoy/#setting-up-gitlab-cicd)

```yaml
image: registry.gitlab.com/<USERNAME>/laravel-sample:latest

services:
  - mysql:5.7

variables:
  MYSQL_DATABASE: homestead
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
  DB_HOST: mysql
  DB_USERNAME: root

stages:
  - test
  - deploy

unit_test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - cp .env.example .env
    - composer install
    - php artisan key:generate
    - php artisan migrate
    - vendor/bin/phpunit

...
```

There should be no `docker run --rm` command inside that `gitlab-ci.yml`.

Comment: But the image doesn't exist yet, I want to test it first before building the image...

Comment: I also have a docker-compose-test.yml which I run after the composer install, that starts the application and runs the unit tests. This worked, but now I want the docker compose as seperate process from the dockerfile. Also I use `artifacts` in the pipeline for `vendor` which causes the composer install to be useful for my application, so my app does benefit from this en the container will be removed, but not the result

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk That is why the guide I mention in the answer *builds* an image first (and publish it), in order to use it by GitLab CI/CD.

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk "I want the docker compose as separate process from the dockerfile": and that is where the issues are starting from.

Comment: Okay I will try that. Could you explain to my building the image first is more efficient for the pipeline, because I still don't see the the benefit?

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk The pipeline can execute the Laravel project deployment in an execution environment, represented by the base image you would have built first: no docker-in-docker needed.

Comment: It worked, but using this method my registry will store a lot of not working images then right? If the pipeline fails the image will still be stored on the server?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252215/discussion-between-vonc-and-a-vreeswijk).

Comment: I still don't see the benefits in building and pushing the image first before testing if it even works?